# itgenube001 on connecting to Exact Online with Invantive Data Hub

Tags: windows-server-2016, invantive-data-hub

What do I have to do about this memory issue?

Error:

> itgenube001: This application requires a physical memory of at least 2 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Invantive Data Hub requires at least 2 GB of memory.

Especially when you are running with XML APIs of Exact Online on a 64-bit server platform, you will allocate a lot of strings which each will involve a pointer to a memory address.

It is required that you have at least 2 GB of physical memory and add swap space as much as required, for instance 4 GB, bringing the total to 6 GB.

Comment: Works after upgrading VM from 1 to 2 GB and adding virtual memory.